# Can someone explain how do the mechanism for this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Do you protonate the oxygen first?

Comment: The dihydrofuran is an enol ether. You should try protonating it as if it were an enolate/enol to make a oxocarbenium ion first.

Answer (score 3):

I think the mechanism will be something like this,
[image]

In first step the hydrogen attached to $C_2$ as the carbocation on $C_1$ is more stable.